# How to check a email in linux server automatically?

Tags: linux, server, ubuntu-14.04, email

I have a Ubuntu 14 server, I have to assign a email account to this server, when some person write a email to this account, the server have to open this mail automatically, and check if there are a specific information, if yes some thing happen.

I suppose that the email are stored in a data base o something like that, but I not have any idea how to start.

Any Idea

Comment: Depends a bit... If you want to really send the email to that system you will have to install an `smtp` server to accept the email and setup a correct DNS MX record. Implementations like `postfix` allow to fill "hooks" with some call to be executed when a message comes in. Easier is to use just an account on some existing, external server and only access that via the `pop3` or `imap4` email protocols supported by most clients. Also script languages have extensions for those protocols which allows you to write a short script which polls for new messages on a periodical base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your question, what you need is a mail alias to a command.

The following may depend on the actual mail server that you use, at least it is relevant for good old sendmail, and postfix. The mail system can use an alias database (normally the file `/etc/aliases`) but can be hashed into a binary version. This files can contains plain aliase that simply redirect a mail address to other mail addresses, and can also contain file aliases (the mail is appended to a local file) and program aliases.

In this last case (lines are like `local_address: | /path/to/program`), the program is started for each mail, and it receives the message through its standard input. Read the manual for your mail server for more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

First you should get confident how mail systems work in general on linux machines. A good start would be to dig into the linux documentation project, particularly the linux electronic mail administrator HOWTO, chapter 3 (how electronic mail works): http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Mail-Administrator-HOWTO.html#toc3

Then, you can decide to which extent you want to set up your email account on the ubuntu server (full smtp server, only mail client etc).

As @arkascha mentions in his comment, the least painful way would be to use an existing mail server and fetch mail from there. With scripts, appropriate actions can be taken once a mail has been received.